# From Heathrowstraat to central Amsterdam

Tags: public-transport, amsterdam

I'm going to visit Amsterdam on a 3-day vacation from 22–25 December, and I was wondering if someone could give me some tips on how to get around.

The hotel is on **Heathrowstraat, Westpoort, Amsterdam**

**Edit:**
I'll just get around using public transport. I'd like to visit at least Vondelpark, the Van Gogh Museum and the centre of Amsterdam. From Heathrowstraat, what are the best ways to get to those places? Also I've heard of a "card" that should cost around 25€ and allows to travel with every public transport for **N** days, is it correct? Where can I buy it?

Comment: 2 feet? Buses? Trams? Taxis? Bikes? Other than wanting recommendations, which are explicitly off-topic for the site, I'm not quite clear what your question is?

Comment: @Gagravarr Sorry if the question is too broad, what I'd like to know is what are the best ways to move once there and maybe some tips on what to visit

Comment: I think the OP means how to ambulate.  Willeke will most likely be here shortly to weigh in...

Comment: What transport you should use depends on what you want to do and your ability/preferences.  This is not really meaningfully answerable.

Comment: @dan1111 yeah sorry, I was just searching for tips from someone that maybe already visited and knows well the city

Comment: We can help you with how to get from your hotel to places you are interested in, or similar, but your question is so vauge at the moment as to be unanswerable. If you want general guideance, perhaps pick up a copy of Lonley Planet or similar.

Comment: @CMaster ok thank you, i'll edit my question later with more specific requests

Comment: The problem with renting a bike is the heavy (bike) traffic, which may behave in an unfamiliar way.  If you are comfortable with that, a bike is a great way to get around.   Bring good rain gear.  Otherwise, the trams are great, too.  If you have a destination that is difficult to reach by tram or metro, and you don't have a bike, you can take the occasional taxi.  Check the scale of the city ... you can walk from one end of the central district to the other in 20 or 40 minutes.

Comment: I live near Amsterdam and often go there for the day. I never use my bike in the city. Good public transport which is almost as fast a bike and cheaper if you buy the right pass, compared to several days bike hire. But if you love cycling, go for it. But best will be to use public transport in the city and go out of town for a long ride in the countryside.

Comment: I agree with @phoog bicycle traffic can be very heavy in Amsterdam, but mostly you will find it getting more quiet in a minute, as it is often traffic light related. Start cycling outside the peak hours, say between 9 AM and 3 PM or after 7 PM.

Comment: I've edited the question with some more "specific" informations, can someone answer me? Thanks everyone for your tips and infos :)

Comment: Public transport within Amsterdam City: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37548/ov-chipkaart-or-gvb-day-pass-for-within-amsterdam-travel/46191#46191 But most of the things you mention will be within 60 minutes walking from your hotel, 30 minutes from each other, so it is up to you whether you want a public transport pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you go to Amsterdam, make a simple plan, work out how much you can actually do in the time in the city.
If each day you only take the tram twice, once to go into the center of town and once back to your hotel, you are likely better off with 'one time use' tickets.
But if you want to flit all over, [the pass of the GVB which includes a return rail ticket to the airport.](https://www.ns.nl/producten/en/uitleg-overige-producten/p/amsterdam-travel-ticket) Be aware that with this pass you can only use GVB buses, trams and Metros, not the other buses that are also running in the area.
A good option for you might be the [pass that allows you free travel within the city center as well as free entry to some museums](https://www.iamsterdam.com/en/i-am/i-amsterdam-city-card) and attractions as well as reductions on other things to do in the city.

For more transport information see [this question,](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37548/ov-chipkaart-or-gvb-day-pass-for-within-amsterdam-travel/46191#46191) (remember prices may have gone up.)

Alternatively, if you like cycling and the weather is promising to be good, hiring a bike can be a good option.
Amsterdam is good for cycling, the worst thing for most tourists is that it is too busy. But wait till the traffic lights down the road have changed and get on between the rushes of crowds or wait till after the rush hour, say after 9:00 AM. Get a good map for cyling and work out routes that use cycle routes, you will find that you have many options that way.

I would go to one main museum per day, maybe a small one extra if you see on you really like. Set some time aside for shopping, for sitting outside people watching and enjoy a drink, the traditional Dutch cafes are great for that. You will find them at almost every second corner in much of the city.
These sell drinks from coffee and soft drinks to hard spirits.

Plenty restaurants all over the city, the cheaper ones are mostly in the smaller streets behind the most famous streets or in the general area of sights. 
More information about the city on many websites, likely also on in your language. I like [this one](http://amsterdam.info/), as it seems to cover everything.

[image: Photo of the house boat museum in Amsterdam]
*This is one of the small museums you might like to add, the Houseboat museum.*
Photo by Willeke and can be used under Creative Commons rules.

Comment: thank you very much, these are exactly the informations I wanted! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may find a useful article about public transportation in Amsterdam is quite extensive and I think covers basic knowledge to know for the first visit.
https://www.shortwalk.me/amsterdam-guide-to-public-transportation/

Metro and trains are well organized and there are maps if your phone would die. Amsterdam is not big and you can walk a lot especially if the weather is good.